# Can not add thumbnail image to MP4 using FFMPEG CLI

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, metadata, thumbnails, mp4

After searching for hours, about the easiest solution for adding a thumbnail to an MP4 using a CLI, I came back to the start "FFMPEG". Though I skipped it at first wishing I will get a working tool but no, I will stick to "FFMPEG".

Even after updating the repository ==> Same issue.

I followed the exact code present at the [official documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) that says:

`ffmpeg -i path/to/in.mp4 -i path/to/IMAGE.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic path/to/out.mp4`

The following error log shows:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x1fd0860] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0x1fd0860] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to rgb24.
[mp4 @ 0x1f747e0] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x1f747e0] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
Error initializing output stream 0:2 -- 
Conversion failed!
```

I have no idea how to fix this. I read the issues forum of the website but I did not find a similar issue. So I hope you guys will give a hand.

Any suggested edits will be taken into consideration.

**Edit1:**

Test1: I brought an image(thumbnail) from the video itself and ran the command.

Test2: I brought a unique image(thumbnail) with different resolutions than the video yet the same error appears.

==>Useless

**Edit2:**

First:

After fixing my command to be like this
`ffmpeg -i path/to/in.mp4 -i path/to/IMAGE.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic -strict -2 path/to/out.mp4`
I viewed the thumbnail using VLC (video player) so it showed up at first. But when I replaced the video and the thumbnail image with others I ran the command it runned smoothly, untill I viewed thumbnail again using VLC it showed the old thumbnail image it seemed to be cached somewhere during "FFMPEG" process. I had to delete the folder and make a new one in order to update the new thumbnail, but again it "caches" the first thumbnail used and shows it in VLC.

Is it an issue from VLC or the "FFMPEG" is doing something weird?

Second:

After I had the thumbnail showing up in VLC I wanted to test this feature by sending it to a contact on WhatsApp but it didn't show. After a little search, I realized it might be connected to "og:image" metadata. Is there a way to edit this using CLI?

Third:

Further, the video embedded with a thumbnail doesn't play on Windows nor on iPhone nor on Android. When I open this using windows media player it says

> Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.

From here I think there is something I have to do with the codec.

Note: the thumbnail shows in Windows File Explorer (but can not play video)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Well the solution is right there at the end of the error log. You're trying to put an Opus encoded audio track in an MP4 which is experimental, so add `-strict -2` like it says.

Comment: @aergistal I added this at the end of the command is this right? Becuase it still shows same error.

Comment: You have to put it before `path/to/out.mp4`.

Comment: @aergistal It worked without errors, then I tested it by VLC ==> It worked well. The next step is to send the video to a mobile device and check this feature (thumbnail). Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's weird why the documents don't write `-strict -2` in the command from first if it was an experimental feature.

Comment: The experimental part is not about the image attachment, it's about the audio codec. If your source MP4 had an audio codec commonly supported by MP4 (like `AAC` for example) you wouldn't see the warning.

Comment: @aergistal After sending the video to my friend over WhatsApp sadly the thumbnail doesn't appear. I think it is something related to metadata `og:image` seems so popular. Do you have any ideas? Please check my edit.

Comment: "It's weird why the documents don't write -strict -2 in the command from first if it was an experimental feature." Which documents?

Comment: @llogan I meant the [official documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).